# Sharing code across queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Lets say I have these queries:

```
select * from test_table where id = 1 order by id limit 10 offset 0
select * from test_table where id = 1 order by name limit 10 offset 0
select * from test_table where id = 1 order by age limit 10 offset 0
```

Assume test_table has the fields `id, name, age`. As you can see, the queries are almost exactly the same with the only exception being order by changes between them. I cannot parametrize the order by clause as that is not supported. Is there any other way to limit the number of queries I write. Is there a view I can define or some other way to share the code across multiple queries?

Answer (score 0):

When you have to dynamically set identifiers (basically, table and column names) of a query, your only option is to dynamically execute the query inside a PL/plSQL function. For your case that would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_query(order_col name) RETURNS SETOF test_table AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
       format('select * from test_table where id = 1 order by %I limit 10 offset 0', order_col);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You then use the query like this, using any of the column names from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM my_query('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `psql` it could be:

```
# \set query 'select * from test_table where id = 1 order by :order limit 10 offset 0;'
# \set order 'id'
# :query
(results here ordered by id)
# \set order 'name desc'
# :query
(results here ordered by name desc)
...
```

`psql` automatically replaces macros like `:<name>` by the values specified by the `\set` commands and doing it recursively.

You can also specify the macros in the command line using `-v` option like

```
$ psql -v "query=select * from test_table where id = 1 order by :order limit 10 offset 0;" -v "order=age"
```